# How to disable input fields in Web2Py

Tags: python, web2py

Is there a quick way - besides looping over the form - to `disable` an input field while defining a table?
Setting the field to `writable=False` displays the data but not in a input-field.

Something like `disable=True` would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the field's widget:

```
db.define_table('mytable',
    Field('myfield', type='string',
          widget=lambda f, v: SQLFORM.widgets.string.widget(f, v, _disabled=True)))
```

Be careful, though -- when the form is submitted, the browser will not send any data for the disabled field, but `SQLFORM` will still be expecting a value (because `writable=True`). So, if you have a validator that requires a value, you will need a workaround (e.g., setting the field's value in `request.post_vars` prior to form processing or defining a custom validator).

Comment: In my case this solution works well - the form fields are submitted on blur, so no default form processing is happening.

Comment: I just found out that it is possible to pass any argument to the widget like `widget=lambda f, v: SQLFORM.widgets.string.widget(f, v, _disabled=True, _superhero='Phantomas')`. Thanks!